# Convert Word Range to Html in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to convert a Word Range to Html. I know how to convert Word document, but how can I convert only a Range from a word document?

The code that converts a full Word document looks like this:

```
private string GetHtmlFromRange(Range range)
{
  XElement html;

  byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.docx");
  using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
      HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
      {
        PageTitle = "My Page Title"
      };
      html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);

      File.WriteAllText("Test.html", html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
    }
  }

  return html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you are using HtmlConverter from [PowerTools for OpenXML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) then you cannot perform the conversion directly from a MemoryStream. To convert a range you would first need to parse your original document and create a new document containing only your desired range OR specify the paragraph objects to include in the new document instead of a range. In either case, the conversion would happen after the new document has been defined. This is because the object model doesn't use ranges; character ranges are a property of the rendered document.

So, your options are either A) to first parse your rendered document so that you are working with your desired range (using the [DocumentBuilder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx) methods) or B) parse your converted html to select the elements corresponding to your desired range using something like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

For my solution, I realized every use case required the user to already have MS Office installed, so I just used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`:

1) define the range you want to select (e.g., from position 5 to position 100,  including non-printing characters),

```
        var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        object start = 5;
        object end = 100;
        var originalText = doc.ActiveWindow.Selection;
```

2) copy the range to a new document

```
        var newDocument = new Word.Document();
        newDocument.Range().FormattedText = doc.Range(start, end).FormattedText;
```

3) save the new document

```
        object nullParameter = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object outputFileName = @"D:\converted.html";
        object fileFormat = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML;
        newDocument.SaveAs(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat);
        newDocument.Close(ref nullParameter, ref nullParameter, ref nullParameter);
```

4) use System.IO to access the output file and do whatever you want with the contents and delete it when you are done.

It's not at all elegant, but if you're using interop anyway, elegance may not be a requirement.